# android:choiceMode attribute in ListView of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have made NavigationDrawer by reading the http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html 
there is a mention of android:choiceMode attribute and I want to know its significance. Can anyone explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It defines the choice mode means at a time how many items you can select at a time. By default, ListView don’t have any choice made implemented. By setting the choiceMode:
By setting the choiceMode To singleChoice, the list allows up to one item to be in a chosen state.
By setting the choiceMode To multipleChoice, the list allows any number of items to be chosen.